# Kotlin reflection with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, kotlin-coroutines

I need to call the method `suspend fun insert(e: T)` by reflection declared as follows:

```
interface IMutableDao<T> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insert(e: T)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(e: T)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(e: T)
}
```

I tried with:

```
val insertFun = IMutableDao::class.functions.find {
            it.name.equals("insert", true)
        }
insertFun!!.callSuspend(dao, o)
```

But I get the exception "`Callable expects 3 arguments, but 2 were provided.`". I do not understand where the 3rd argument comes from.

**UPDATE**

I have found the problem. The 3rd is a Continuation instance. Does anyone know what to pass there ? I couldn't find any suitable instance.

**UPDATE 2**

The workaround I found was to create a temporary class inside the function I call the suspended function from, like this:

```
val c = object : Continuation<Unit> {
override val context: CoroutineContext
get() = EmptyCoroutineContext
        override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Unit>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows no error in my case, what's your Kotlin version and environment?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "this" parameter which is the object that the method should be called with respect to.

it should be the first argument to the method.

Comment: there is,  it's the dao argument, Anyway I found the problem, but there is another one. See please the UPDATE maybe you have more suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You may use [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) with Unit as type and use the continuation instance.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
        insertFun!!.callSuspend(dao, o, continuation)
    }
}
```